# How can multiple pages be model with xstate

Tags: xstate

I am trying to build a real world application with xstate but I am having trouble with modeling the application startup.

a user can enter the application start by typing the [www.ex.com](http://www.ex.com) to go the home page
but a user can also enter the application [www.ex.com/any-page](http://www.ex.com/any-page)

can someone give an example of modeling application with multiple pages

**a user can be unauthenticated an be on the login page or home page but not secure page**

or

**a user can be authenticated and be on any page**

I want each page to have there own state that is what is prompting the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want each page to have there own state that is what is prompting the question.

Don't think of it that way; at least not at first. Use a data-first approach, such as in this example: https://codesandbox.io/s/xstate-react-back-example-4q2vh

The reason is that each page isn't necessarily a "finite state" - it's just data, and all part of the same state (e.g., "viewing a page"). The best way to think about finite state is as an application's *behavior* at any given time. Does the behavior change when changing pages? Probably not, so use `context` instead of finite state.